# How can I launch this Agora WebRTC sample node.js server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, webrtc, agora.io

I'm node.js beginner and try to use Agora WebRTC SDK with reading this document.

https://docs.agora.io/en/user_guide/communication/webrtc_user_guide_communication.html#qs-communication-webrtc

Regarding sever topic in this Document,
At first, I used "npm install" command to make nodo_modules.
Next, I check APP_ID and APP_CERTIFICATE in ./server/nodejs/DemoServer.js.
But I could not find them. Where should I fill in the value of APP_ID and APP_CERTIFICATE in DemoServer.js? VENDER_KEY?

WebRTC Sample code is located in this download link.(No plug-ins)
https://www.agora.io/en/blog/download/

Please help me to launch this sample.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the app certificate for the Video Call sample, just the appID.

The app ID (key) is being retrieved via user input on the HTML page itself.

`Key: <input id="key" type="text" value="" size="36"></input>`

```
console.log("Init AgoraRTC client with vendor key: " + key.value);
client = AgoraRTC.createClient({mode: 'interop'});
client.init(key.value, function () {
    console.log("AgoraRTC client initialized");
```

Comment: Can we create token and channel through loopback nodejs API.?